# How to create a specific language copy of a page with REST API?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, api, pages, localization

I came across [this article](https://www.eliostruyf.com/multilingual-apis-modern-sharepoint/), which states that a language copy can be created with an API call like this:

```
POST https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename/_api/sitepages/pages(<Source page ID>)/translations/create
```

The request body should be like this:

```
{
  "request": {
    "__metadata": {
      "type": "SP.TranslationStatusCreationRequest"
    },
    "LanguageCodes": {
      "results": ["nl-nl"]
    }
  }
}
```

This is not working for me, I get an error on this. More exactly, it creates a language copy for all available languages (despite the error message), while I need to create a language copy only for the specified language.

Here's the error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException",
        "message": {
            "lang": "en-US",
            "value": "The type SP.TranslationStatusCollection does not support HTTP PATCH method."
        }
    }
}
```

I tried a bunch of bodies to no avail ([found this](https://github.com/pnp/pnpcore/issues/246) as well, changed *set* to *create* but runs into the same error).

What would be the correct request body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. The call needs exactly these three headers with the correct values:

```
Accept: application/json; odata=verbose
Content-Type: application/json; odata=verbose
odata-version: 3.0
```

Unlike many other POST requests to SharePoint, this doesn't need *x-http-method* nor *if-match*.